# Font of DOS in assembly language

Tags: assembly

I wrote a program with assembly language in DOS and after running it the font of DOS gets more larger, any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You probably changed the screen (or DOS emulation window) resolution...

Comment: what changes resoulation? and how can i undo it ?

Comment: Change font size in your shortcut's properties windows.

Comment: Did you invoke `int 0x10` to set graphic mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using `int 10h` service to change the screen mode (function `AH=00h`), you should save the old mode at the start of your program and restore it before exiting. You can query the current mode with `int 10h AH=0Fh` (mode is returned in `AL`).

Here's a random example from Google:

```
;; read current video mode and save
        mov ah,0fh
        int 10h
        mov vmode,al
        mov vpage,bh
;; set video mode
        mov ah,0
        mov al,VIDMOD
        int 10h

        [....]

;; restore old video mode
        mov bh,vpage
        mov al,vmode
        mov ah,0
        int 10h

        mov ax, 4c00h   ;exit
        int 21h
```